# How to import curved nav bar appropriately?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I would like to use curved navigation bar in my app, but when I run my code it shows this error.

*Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:curved_navigation_bar/home.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.*

Any help? Thanks a lot.

main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
```

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code of code-image?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Check [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar). You have to add `curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3` dependency in pubspec.yaml and execute flutter pub get then this import will work

Change import statement to

```
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
```

Comment: Yup. I have added to it already. Also excuted flutter pub get.

Comment: Edited my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

When ever you wish to use any package, you need add it using command

```dart
flutter pub add curved_navigation_bar
```

Or by
opening `pubspec.yaml` file and  provide packageName:version under `dependencies`.

A better guide is to follow [installation section](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar/install) on package.

Answer (score 0):

In the `main.dart` file you have imported `home.dart` with mistake.
change `'package:curved_navigation_bar/home.dart'` to the correct path of `home.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/home.dart'; //Here 

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```